# Using a mod diamond in normal user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Is using a mod diamond in the text of the user profile OK?

The following example clearly states that it is fake, but at first glance this could made users misleadingly think the user would be a mod.

[image]

For [users names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230643/237989) and [profile images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230643/237989), it is already established that users should not try to look like a moderator.

Comment: Do you mean somebody had `♦`  in their name and their profile says it's fake, or it's just in the profile and it says it's fake?

Comment: No, just in the profile text as shown in the screenshot

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: What's the argument here? Prohibit ♦ in profile text? I think it's already prohibited in usernames, where it would be more likely to cause confusion.

Comment: @yivi Yes, even though it was worse in user names, I think it is still misleading in profiles.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188555/348196

Comment: Not sure how putting in a diamond in the text is any different than putting in any of the other playing card symbols: `♥`, `♠` and `♣`. We also have several users named "Community", but only one have a diamond attached to their username.

Comment: @Scratte It should be clear from what a diamond conveys on a Stack Exchange site how it is different from other arbitrary symbols of your choosing.

Comment: I used to have a ♦ in my "location" in my profile. I got a mod message sent explaining that that's not allowed. I then changed it on all of my network profiles.

Comment: @10Rep I think the issue there was that was the *only* character in that field. I can see that being confusing (it's the first field shown as well). So not exactly the same as the scenario here (lest anyone be confused)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are a number of legitimate uses for the symbol in regular user's profiles:

- Saying you're a mod on another site or a former mod (when true)
- Talking about mods
- Quoting/linking to something that uses it
- Visually representing playing cards
- Etc.

Most users won't be using the symbol improperly. Here's a user who falls under the first bullet: [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel).

If you see someone misusing the symbol, drop a flag on one of their posts. It's not acceptable to pretend to be a moderator/employee. A real moderator can edit or reset their profile.

Comment: @Kev I suspect rather than hyperbole, "abusively" was just intended to refer to ["abuse"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abuse) in the sense of "misuse", "improper use", etc

Comment: @Kev  It's abuse to try to impersonate a mod/employee.

Comment: @Kev Good to see you fight against internet hyperbole. Do you know Twitter? ;)

Comment: "reset profile" as in zero rep and delete all posts?

Comment: @Kev: "Abuse" can just mean "put to a wrong or improper use". It doesn't specifically refer to harming people. There's no hyperbole involved. See a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abuse).

Comment: Also ["abusive: characterized by wrong or improper use or action"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abusive).

Answer (score 33):

It makes no sense to forbid specific characters from being used in a free text field such as the user profile. You'd only be restricting legitimate uses of said character.

That said, if you see someone *trying* to make it seem like they're a moderator, just flag one of their posts and explain the situation. A moderator will take care of it if necessary.

Comment: *"A moderator will take care of it if necessary"* - Hopefully a *real* one xD